# Column created not recognised in R

Tags: r

I am working on a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/garystafford/environmental-sensor-data-132k) that has included temperature and three environmental conditions. Those conditions are based on the device ID which was placed in that environmental condition to measure data. Using R, I created the new column `EnvCond`  using `mutate` and it does appear in the new dataset, as in the code below:

```
IoT_telemetry_data <- mutate(IoT_telemetry_data, 
    EnvCond = ifelse(device=="00:0f:00:70:91:0a", "Stable Cooler Humid", 
              ifelse(device=="1c:bf:ce:15:ec:4d", "Variable Temperature Humid", 
                    "Stable Warm Dry")))
```

The screenshot below shows the column added into the same table:
[image]
However, I am trying to use this new column to create three different variables; each one of them should contain the temperature measured for each of the three conditions. I tried using `select` to create one of those variables, as in the code below:

```
#Table that has only the temperature for Stable Cooler Humid environment:
TempSCH <- select(IoT_telemetry_data, temp, where(EnvCond == "Stable Cooler Humid"))
```

I get an error that `EnvCond` isn't found.
I tried using the pipe operator `%>%` from the `ggplot` library to attach that variable to the data, and I am using `attach(data)` in my code as well, but I still get the error.
Is the condition inside `select` written incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering like this instead

```r
library(tidyverse)

IoT_telemetry_data %>% 
  filter(EnvCond == "Stable Cooler Humid")
```

e.g. this should give you what you're after

```r
IoT_telemetry_data %>% 
  select(temp, EnvCond) %>% 
  filter(EnvCond == "Stable Cooler Humid")
```